# Prove $\bigcap_\alpha P(A_\alpha)=P(\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove $\bigcap_\alpha P(A_\alpha)=P(\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha)$

Where $P$ denotes the power set.

Definition: $\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha=\{\forall\alpha\in A:x\in\ A_\alpha\}$

**My work:**

$x \in \bigcap_\alpha P(A_\alpha)\iff \forall\alpha\in P(A):x\in\ P(A_\alpha)\iff\forall\alpha\in A:x\in\ A_\alpha\iff \forall\alpha\in A:x\in\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha $

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: I added the set-theory tag. Are you sure the general topology tag is appropriate?

Comment: You need to correct the third and fourth steps.  In the third line note that $x \in A_{\alpha}$ is a type error, it should be $x \subseteq A_{\alpha}$. The fourth line should remove "for all $\alpha$" since you are already intersecting these.

Comment: Also, you write somewhere $\forall \alpha \in P(A)$, but this also looks like a type error, $\alpha$ is just an index and likely it is not useful to think of it as being inside a power set of anything.  I'm also a bit confused with your terminology, $\cap_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$ is clear, yet the "definition" as $\{\forall \alpha \in A : x \in A_{\alpha}\}$ is not, I'm not sure how to even parse that ("for all $\alpha$ such that $x$ is in $A_{\alpha}$"?).  I would define the intersection as $\{x : x \in A_{\alpha}  \mbox{ for all $\alpha$}\}$.

Comment: It would help if you would explain how you view the $:$ symbol.  I view it as "such that," I don't know how you view it.  It may be better to write in words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be more careful in your use of quantifiers and in the definition of arbitrary intersections. My proof:
$$x \in \bigcap_{\alpha}\mathcal{P}(A_{\alpha}) \Leftrightarrow \forall \alpha(x \in \mathcal{P}(A_{\alpha})) \Leftrightarrow \forall \alpha(x \subseteq A_{\alpha}) \Leftrightarrow x \subseteq \bigcap_{\alpha}A_{\alpha} \Leftrightarrow x \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcap_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}) $$

The third logical equivalence is the only one that demands proof (although it is not hard to see, just note that conjunctions are distributive over the universal quantifier).

Comment: Oh, yeah is more clear your proof. I'm need be more careful in the use of quantifiers. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing Bvss12 will never give me an explanation of how he/she views the $:$ symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you prove the two inclusions separately.

First a lemma: *If $X\subseteq Y$, then $P(X)\subseteq P(Y)$.*

Indeed, a subset of $X$ is also a subset of $Y$.

With the lemma at hand, and setting $A=\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha$, we can conclude from $A\subseteq A_\alpha$ that $P(A)\subseteq P(A_\alpha)$. Since this holds for every $\alpha$, we have
$$
P(A)\subseteq \bigcap_{\alpha}P(A_\alpha).
$$

Conversely, suppose $C\in\bigcap_{\alpha}P(A_\alpha)$. Then $C\in P(A_\alpha)$, for every $\alpha$. Thus, by definition, $C\subseteq A_\alpha$, for every $\alpha$, and therefore $C\subseteq A=\bigcap_{\alpha}A_\alpha$, proving that $C\in P(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

We show $$\bigcap_\alpha P(A_\alpha)=P(\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha)$$

Note that an element of $\bigcap_\alpha P(A_\alpha)$ is a set which is a subset of every $A_\alpha$.

Thus it is a subset of the intersection $\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha$

Therefore it is an element of the power set $ P(\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha)$

On the other hand every element of $ P(\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha)$ is a subset of $\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha$

Thus it is a subset of every $A_\alpha$

Therefore it is an element of every $P(A_\alpha)$.

Thus it belongs to $\bigcap_\alpha P(A_\alpha)$